# GlassFish build failed

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb-3.0, glassfish-3

Each time I try to deploy my server side code, the build fails. If I try to restart my machine, the build is successful but fails later when I try to build the subsequent times. I get the following Severe messages when I attempt to build:

```
SEVERE: "IOP00410216: (COMM_FAILURE) Unable to create IIOP listener on the specified host/port: localhost/3820"
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 216  completed: No


WARNING: Can not find resource bundle for this logger.  class name that failed: org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory
        WARNING: Exception getting SocketInfo
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization eror


WARNING: "IOP02310202: (OBJ_ADAPTER) Error in connecting servant to ORB"
org.omg.CORBA.OBJ_ADAPTER:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 202  completed: No
```

Following are the details for the severe method:

```
SEVERE: "IOP00410216: (COMM_FAILURE) Unable to create IIOP listener on the specified host/port: localhost/3820"
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 216  completed: No
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.createListenerFailed(ORBUtilSystemException.java:3835)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.createListenerFailed(ORBUtilSystemException.java:3855)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.initialize(SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.java:98)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.CorbaTransportManagerImpl.getAcceptors(CorbaTransportManagerImpl.java:247)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.CorbaTransportManagerImpl.addToIORTemplate(CorbaTransportManagerImpl.java:264)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.oa.ObjectAdapterBase.initializeTemplate(ObjectAdapterBase.java:131)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.oa.toa.TOAImpl.<init>(TOAImpl.java:130)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.oa.toa.TOAFactory.getTOA(TOAFactory.java:114)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.connect(ORBImpl.java:1740)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.presentation.rmi.StubAdapter.connect(StubAdapter.java:212)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.getIOR(ORBImpl.java:2194)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.getFVDCodeBaseIOR(ORBImpl.java:966)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.glassfish.gmbal.generic.FacetAccessorImpl.invoke(FacetAccessorImpl.java:126)
        at org.glassfish.gmbal.impl.MBeanImpl.invoke(MBeanImpl.java:440)
        at org.glassfish.gmbal.impl.AttributeDescriptor.get(AttributeDescriptor.java:144)
        at org.glassfish.gmbal.impl.MBeanSkeleton.getAttribute(MBeanSkeleton.java:569)
        at org.glassfish.gmbal.impl.MBeanSkeleton.getAttributes(MBeanSkeleton.java:625)
        at org.glassfish.gmbal.impl.MBeanImpl.getAttributes(MBeanImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttributes(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:726)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttributes(JmxMBeanServer.java:665)
        at org.glassfish.admin.amx.util.jmx.MBeanProxyHandler.getAttributes(MBeanProxyHandler.java:273)
        at org.glassfish.admin.amx.core.proxy.AMXProxyHandler.attributesMap(AMXProxyHandler.java:1193)
        at org.glassfish.admin.amx.core.proxy.AMXProxyHandler.attributesMap(AMXProxyHandler.java:1203)
        at org.glassfish.admin.amx.core.proxy.AMXProxyHandler.handleSpecialMethod(AMXProxyHandler.java:414)
        at org.glassfish.admin.amx.core.proxy.AMXProxyHandler._invoke(AMXProxyHandler.java:792)
        at org.glassfish.admin.amx.core.proxy.AMXProxyHandler.invoke(AMXProxyHandler.java:526)
        at $Proxy107.attributesMap(Unknown Source)
        at org.glassfish.admin.amx.core.AMXValidator._validate(AMXValidator.java:642)
        at org.glassfish.admin.amx.core.AMXValidator.validate(AMXValidator.java:1298)
        at org.glassfish.admin.amx.impl.mbean.ComplianceMonitor$ValidatorThread.doRun(ComplianceMonitor.java:256)
        at org.glassfish.admin.amx.impl.mbean.ComplianceMonitor$ValidatorThread.run(ComplianceMonitor.java:227)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:119)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:59)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:52)
        at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.IIOPSSLSocketFactory.createServerSocket(IIOPSSLSocketFactory.java:293)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.initialize(SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl.java:91)
        ... 32 more
```

Comment: cleaning up things tagged with glassfishv3 instead of glassfish. This has no revision marker in the text, so I will keep the revision marker in a tag...

Comment: @vkraemer: how does the tag [`v3`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/v3) at its own make sense?

Comment: I can edit the tags to unify them... I don't have the 2k rep necessary to move the version id into the text of the question...  i do not want the version info to be lost on this question... so the v3 tag is born... I will probably edit the v3 tags away, after I hit the reputation mark necessary to put the version identifier into the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting this problem because my program crashed unexpectedly, while the server was still running. So, each time this happened I cleaned the tcp ports that remained open when the code crashed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some process is using the port 3820.  Since you have said that the first build works okay, I am tempted to say that your build is attempting to start the server, even though it is already started... which would give this kind of error. If you include more info about what you mean when you say 'build', someone may be able to give you a more complete answer.